# DBPedia SPARQL OPTIONAL

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am running this simple query on http://dbpedia.org/sparql

```
PREFIX p: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT * WHERE {
    ?person dcterms:subject category:British_journalists .
    OPTIONAL { ?person p:name ?name } .
    OPTIONAL { ?person p:dateOfBirth ?dob } .

}
LIMIT 10
```

I expect to get the first 10 people from http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:British_journalists whether they have `name` and `dateOfBirth` or not. I am getting the first 10 people who have both properties. For e.g. there are 2 missing people after Andrew Rothstein.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "I expect to get the first 10 people from ..." - why? What makes you think you can rely on any particular ordering when there is none specified?

Comment: As @O.R.Mapper suggested your question is vague. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Point taken. Removing limit brings full result set which reveals that OPTIONAL is in fact working.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your query is that a) `LIMIT` limits the number of *rows* returned, not subjects, and b) some people have more than one name.

So, for example, the journalist Daniel Singer (`http://dbpedia.org/resource/Daniel_Singer_(journalist)`) has at least two names: `"Daniel Singer"@en` and `"Singer, Daniel"@en`. That doubles the number of rows with him as a subject.

If you `GROUP BY ?person` you ensure only one person per row. You then need to `SAMPLE` names and dobs to pick just one per person.

```
PREFIX p: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT ?person (SAMPLE(?name) as ?aname) (SAMPLE(?dob) as ?adob) WHERE {
    ?person dcterms:subject category:British_journalists .
    OPTIONAL { ?person p:name ?name } .
    OPTIONAL { ?person p:dateOfBirth ?dob } .
}
GROUP BY ?person
LIMIT 10
```

(I'm not sure how well `SAMPLE` plays with unbound cases, i.e. where there isn't a name)

Comment: Thanks! This is a great trick when one needs a single record per person and any sample name is acceptable. The original query gave me all name variants.

Comment: If you want all the variants you can use a different aggregator: `GROUP_CONCAT(?name ; separator=",")` rather than `SAMPLE`. That makes a single value with all the names.

Answer (score 0):

As per O.R Mapper's comment - removing the limit brings full result set which reveals that OPTIONAL is in fact working. 
Thank you.